# RedirectMatch and hide URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say there is a webpage called `me.com` where I want the file from `/project/index.php` to be the main root file.

`/project/index.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
header('Location: /project/site-one.html');
exit;
?>
```

the `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RedirectMatch ^/$ /project/index.php [L]

    # more rules follow
```

now if I visit `me.com` I get `me.com/project/site-one.html`

What I want is, always if there is `/project/site-one.html` or `/project/index.php` 
to just show `me.com` in the adressbar as URL.

How is this possible? I've tried with RewriteRule and just passing the [L] flag but nothing does what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .htaccess like this in root .htaccess (a level above `project`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /project/site-one.html [L]
```

You should remove `header(...)` function call from your `index.php`

Comment: Thank you. I've add `DirectoryIndex site-one.html index.php index.html` which almost works fine. I still get `me.com/project/` and actually just want `me.com` . . .

Comment: With `RedirectMatch ^/?$ /project/site-one.html [L]` the redirect works but then in the adress bar I see `me.com/project/site-one.html` and I just want `me.com`

Comment: thank you! don't know why it bluddy didn't work before! now it does!

Comment: As you notice you need to use `RewriteRule` instead of `RedirectMatch`.